# How to read first and last line from cat output?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, grep

I have text file. Task - get first and last line from file after

```
$ cat file | grep -E "1|2|3|4" | commandtoprint

$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
```

Need this without cat output (only 1 and 5).

```
~$ cat file | tee >(head -n 1) >(wc -l)
1
2
3
4
5
5
1
```

Maybe awk and more shorter solution exist...

Comment: In your second example, `wc -l` has nothing to do with outputting the last line of a file.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

**sed** Solution:

```
sed -e 1b -e '$!d' file
```

When reading from `stdin` if would look like this (for example `ps -ef`):

```
ps -ef | sed -e 1b -e '$!d'
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      1931  1837  0 20:05 pts/0    00:00:00 sed -e 1b -e $!d
```

**head & tail** Solution:

```
(head -n1 && tail -n1) <file
```

When data is coming from a command (`ps -ef`):

```
ps -ef 2>&1 | (head -n1 && tail -n1)
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      2068  1837  0 20:13 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
```

**awk** Solution:

```
awk 'NR==1; END{print}' file
```

And also the piped example with `ps -ef`:

```
ps -ef | awk 'NR==1; END{print}'
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      1935  1837  0 20:07 pts/0    00:00:00 awk NR==1; END{print}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's the best answer because i cannot do `(head -n1 file;tail -n1 file)` i have very big command and pipe as last symbol. So `| sed '1p;$!d'` shorter one.

Comment: Sorry for my English, if you don't understand me - it's my problem - tell me about it and i prepare better presentation for you.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for this Note! Demo: file with only 1. Command `$ cat file | sed '1p;$!d'` #return `1 1` and `$ cat file | awk 'NR==1; END{print}'` return `1 1`

Comment: Can we generalise this if we replace 'file' by an arbitrary process writing to stdout?

Comment: @gerrit i added your suggestions

Comment: @chaos - though in almost every situation it would not matter, there are certain rare cases in which you might need to ensure you always get the first and last line directly following one another. With sed you can do `1h;$!d;x;G;1g` - that way the output of the first and last lines will always instantaneously follow one another, and in the event of a single line input you'll always only get the singe line out.

Comment: Can you explain the sed one(s)? Even after a look at the sed man page, I'm still confused (this is a common occurrence for me with the sed man page).

Comment: Does `head && tail` really work for you? `seq 10 | (head -n1 && tail -n1)` prints `1` only.

Comment: @glennjackman That annoyed me too a bit. The `head && tail` part is not always working. Switch to line buffered stream, then it works: `stdbuf -oL seq 10 | (head -n1 && tail -n1)` print `1` and `10` for me.

Comment: @DavidConrad `-e 1b` means match line number 1 continue `-e '$!d'` means: `$` match the last line, `!` invert and `d` delete. So: match everything but the last line and delete it.

Comment: @DavidConrad, to elaborate on what chaos said, `-e 1b` -- on the first line, branch to the end of the sed script, at which point the implicit "print" happens. If the input is only one line long, sed ends. Otherwise, for all lines except the last, delete. On the last line, the implicit "print" happens again.

Comment: @mikeserv: Why do you use `1g` at the end of your sed script ? Using it crushes the contents of the pattern space with that of the hold space, which is just the last line. Shouldn't you be already well served by `seq 10 | sed '1h;$!d;x;G' ` ?

Comment: @cbhihe - not sure - just on my phone w/ 3% charge and only a single sock, but i would guess it is to prevent getting the first line twice if input is only a single line

Comment: @mikeserv: ;-)  check it when you get a chance. On a single line it efectively prevents doubling it on output, but on a multiple line work-case, it just preserves the last line... at least on GNU `sed` 4.2.2. Cheers.

Comment: @cbhihe - you know i would check it, but the CVPD has my computer on a $150 hock and the rest of my things burned up with my house when they torched it. its a weir'd life.

Comment: @cbhihe - that expression does `$!d`... so the only case when a `1g` should *crush* the output is a case of a oneline input file, barring a continued live scenario with more than one last line...

Comment: @mikeserv: yup. agreed ! But talk about long lived thread and necroposting... 4 yrs and going strong. Hope all yr woes from back in Sep.'16 are behind you.

Comment: @cbhihe - the mad hatter said unbirthdays make us young again. the dormouse helped him drink his wine. but i say, `if ! kill -0 $$; then ! $0 -ba</; fi`

Comment: @glennjackman try with `(head -n1 && tail -n1) <<< $(seq 10)`

Answer (score 34):

`sed -n '1p;$p' file.txt` will print 1st and last line of file.txt .

Comment: Note that if the input has only one line, it will be printed twice. You may prefer `sed -e 1b -e '$!d'` if you don't want that.

Answer (score 11):

A funny pure Bash≥4 way:

```
cb() { (($1-1>0)) && unset "ary[$1-1]"; }
mapfile -t -C cb -c 1 ary < file
```

After this, you'll have an array `ary` with first field (i.e., with index `0`) being the first line of `file`, and its last field being the last line of `file`. The callback `cb` (optional if you want to slurp all lines in the array) unsets all the intermediate lines so as to not clutter memory. As a free by-product, you'll also have the number of lines in the file (as the last index of the array+1).

Demo:

```
$ mapfile -t -C cb -c 1 ary < <(printf '%s\n' {a..z})
$ declare -p ary
declare -a ary='([0]="a" [25]="z")'
$ # With only one line
$ mapfile -t -C cb -c 1 ary < <(printf '%s\n' "only one line")
$ declare -p ary
declare -a ary='([0]="only one line")'
$ # With an empty file
$ mapfile -t -C cb -c 1 ary < <(:)
declare -a ary='()'
```

Answer (score 10):

With `sed` you could `d`elete lines if *NOT* the `1`st one *AND NOT* the la`$`t one.
Use `!` to `NOT` (negate) a condition and the `X{Y..}` construct to combine `X` *AND* `Y` conditions:

```
cmd | sed '1!{$!d;}'
```

or you could use a range - from `2`nd to la`$`t - and delete all lines in that range except the la`$`t line:

```
cmd | sed '2,${$!d;}'
```

Answer (score 8):

Without cat:

```
$ cat file |tee >(head -n1) >(tail -n1) >/dev/null
1
5
```

or

```
$ (head -n1 file;tail -n1 file)
1
5
```

Comment: In the first one, the order of the lines is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 7):

Using Perl:

```
$ seq 10 |  perl -ne 'print if 1..1 or eof'
1
10
```

The above prints the first item in the output of `seq 10` via the `if 1..1`, while the `or eof` will also print the last item.

Comment: Could you explain how this works? Please avoid giving such one-liner answers without an explanation of what they do and how.

Comment: what do `/etc` `abrt` and `yum.repos.d` have to do this question?

Comment: @drs I edited the answer to avoid using 'ls' as sample input.

Comment: @dolmen: might be a good idea to finish editing by suppressing all reference to /etc. I guess such was added after yr first edit, but, all the same, as it stands the answer makes no sense at all. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Good answer. I used it for an alias: `alias firstlast='perl -ne "print if 1..1 or eof"'`. Now I can `seq 10|firstlast`.  With `$.` containing the line number, replacing `1..1` with `$.==1` might be more readable for those unfamiliar with Perl's flip-flop dot-dot operator.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ seq 100 | { IFS= read -r first; echo "$first"; tail -1; }
1
100
```

Comment: Works great for a `sed.... | ` pipe input!